# Can I sign and redeem many outputs at the same time? (shrink the size of a tx Input)

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, signature, performance, p2sh

I'm looking [at this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/ee1658bb4d0de80a91d2e0005218d4cfab7c302a352458bd6afb6376b47fbf81) that is redeeming many historical outputs from the same address.

When I look at the blockchain, it seems pretty clear there is redundancy here of the public key being repeated over and over again.  If I could consolidate that, I could save on transaction fees, and bloat in the blockchain by signing all of them at once.

Is there a way to have one signature redeem many inputs at once?  Perhaps using P2SH?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately by design, each scriptSig is verified slightly differently, so a different sig is required to redeem each input.